# Determine if the function is even, odd or neither $f(x)=x^2$

Tags: functions

Determine if the function  is even, odd or neither $f(x)=x^2$ in interval $0 < x < 2$

My answer?
Its neither but because of the interval. We know that for even function ==> $f(x)=f(-x)$ and odd $f(x)=-f(-x).$

My question!
Is my answer correct? and what if we dont have interval? we could say its even right?

Comment: Well $f(-x)$ isn't even defined

Comment: so my answer is right ?

Comment: i think no it is not true

Comment: This is one of those situations where you have to pay close attention to the definition from the textbook (or notes). If you can't figure it out from there, it's probably worth asking the professor.